# Can route color be modified in MapPoint?

Tags: mappoint

Can route color be modified in MapPoint?

We need to change route colors. There is no reference for
MapPoint I could search for MapPoint.Route, I just have a book.
I don't understand why Microsoft does not create a reference for MapPoint.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick (not exhaustive) search suggests that it's not possible to change route colours, but there may be a workaround: [you can change highlight colours](http://www.mapping-tools.com/howto/drawing-annotation/highlighting-objects/).

The site I linked ([mapping-tools.com/howto](http://www.mapping-tools.com/howto/)) seems to be a reference guide for MapPoint, which you may find handy given that you say you'd like an online resource.

Comment: Ok but how do I highlight the active route?

Comment: The active route is already highlighted, and MapPoint then adds a different highlight for the current route segment - note these are different to the highlight functionality described by HDB (typically a broad yellow highlight). Yes I wrote the above howto :-)